# Is there a on change property for textEdit class in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm trying to create a notepad app in Qt, and I want to do something every time the "TextEdit" is changed.
I've tried to search in the Qt Documentation but I had no luck.
Maybe someone knows how to do it?

Comment: What about [QTextEdit::textChanged()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#textChanged)?

Comment: ok thanks, but how do I know what letter has been added,
I want to print every letter that I add

Comment: There are more signals available. Just scroll up and down in the linked doc. There are even more signals (for more fine grained control) in the document you can obtain by [QTextEdit::document()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#document-prop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont need the property for that... I suggest you to instead connect the signal emited by the object... in this case the textChanged signal

as in the doc specified:

> This signal is emitted whenever the document's content changes; for example, when text is inserted or deleted, or when formatting is applied.

all you need to do in connect the object

```
void MainWindow::on_textEdit_textChanged()
{
    qDebug() << "textChanged: "  << ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
}
```

[image]

Comment: ok, and is there a way to get what has changed like what letter has been added?